# Open and parse JSON file in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is what I try to do:

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file_1", ofType: "json"), let url = URL(string: path) {

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: Data.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)

        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

And what I get is:

> error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “file_1.json” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/195E2A54-5B47-44E2-92AC-25B4074A43D1/Parser.app/file_1.json}

How to workaround this error?

The file exists in my project directory:

[image]

Comment: try deleting built & re-run

Comment: Why don't you use `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)` directly instead of converting a path to an URL?

Comment: ... which magically solves the problem ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

instead of

```
let url = URL(string: path)
```